# Set button width for QWizard pages

Tags: c++, qt, qwizard, qwizardpage

How can I adjust the button width (back, next buttons) of a `QWizard`. Is there any style sheet (qss) option I can use, or do I have to identify the buttons and set the widget width?

The stylesheet approach would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the buttons using the [`button()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html#button) method of `QWizard` and set a fixed width:

```
your_wizard->button(QWizard::BackButton)->setFixedWidth(the_width)
your_wizard->button(QWizard::NextButton)->setFixedWidth(the_width)
```

Comment: That is the 2nd best solution if I cannot do it with a qss style sheet. I mean an external style sheet which selects the wizard, then the button. The problem is to just select the NEXT, BACK ... buttons and not any other button.

Comment: @HorstWalter Well, there is no selector in QSS for the QWizard buttons so QSS will not work